# Flutter: How to change TextFormField prefixIcon not focus color by ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter: I could change the TextFormField prefixIcon focus color by setting Theme.accentColor, but can't find any way to change the prefixIcon color when not focus.

Comment: Please show your code and results, so that we can figure out what has been done. We would like to see what all are the things you have tried as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FocusNode Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html), this will keep a track of when you have the focus on that particular `TextFormField`.

**Note:** Make sure you assign different `FocusNode` object to different `TextFormField()` if you have multiple class.

Here is your solution:

```
FocusNode _focusNode;

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _focusNode.dispose();
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _focusNode = new FocusNode();
  _focusNode.addListener(_onOnFocusNodeEvent);
}

_onOnFocusNodeEvent() {
  setState(() {
    // Re-renders
  });
}

TextFormField(
  focusNode: _focusNode
  decoration: InputDecoration(
     border: InputBorder.none,
     prefixIcon: Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
       child: Icon(
         Icons.search,
         color: this.getPrefixIconColor(),
       ) // icon is 48px widget.
     )
   )
)

//This will change the color of the icon based upon the focus on the field
Color getPrefixIconColor(){
  return _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.black : Colors.grey
}
```

Let me know if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to change the prefixIcon normal color by setting a property of Theme? I don't want to set the color one by one.

Comment: Still you need to get the update which one is in focus, else the machine will get confused. Machine are smart but the way you think, doesn't mean the machine will behave the same. I hope there is a way, but this is the best solution I can give to you. All the best. @JasperLee

Comment: You can upvote the answer, and mark it as correct @JasperLee, for the other people who'd come and see this answer. They'd find it useful. I'm glad it helped you in some manner.